# How to use MOXy's object graph with JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, moxy

I would like to use EclipseLink/MOXy's `@XmlNamedObjectGraph` annotation to specify the object graph a SOAP webservice gets from the persistence layer and returns to a client. As the structure of my underlying data model is quite complex, I would like to avoid the alternative of creating DTOs using ugly data copy procedures.

My problem is that I'm unable to access the JAXB/MOXy marshaller and tell him to use a specific object graph depending on the webservice method. Is this possible after all?

EDIT:
I'm working with TomEE+.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? I'm new to Java EE, spent days and days of researching and this is the first thing I really got stuck - it's a bit discouraging then to see the downvote. If there's something missing I'm more than happy to provide more context!

Comment: How did you build your SOAP web service?  What tools/frameworks are you using?